# Accessing arguments with argv,and how to convert?

Tags: objective-c, argv

In my Objective-C program, I need to pass an argument into `argv[1]`, which would be used in the program.

I want to pass `argv[1]` an argument like:

```
CFStringRef test = CFSTR(argv[1]);
```

but it doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: You should read the documentation, and realize that `CFSTR` is for string constants only. Then, use one of the `CFStringCreate*()` functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the argument as an `NSString` with:

```
NSString *arg1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]];
```